# Convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n} \times (5x)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, factorial, divergent-series

I have to check for which $x$ the series converges/diverges.

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^n} \times (5x)^n$

I know that for $|x| < \frac{1}{5}e$ it converges and for $|x| > \frac{1}{5}e$ it diverges by using the ratio test $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$.
However, this test does not tell me anything about $|x| = \frac{1}{5}e$.

How do I prove that the series diverges for $|x| = \frac{1}{5}e$ ? (Wolfram Alpha told me so)

I thought that it has something to do with $\frac{n!}{x^n}$ which would be $\frac{1}{e^x}$, but I just failed to find a proper proof.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You don't need that ugly $\;\times\;$ there...

Comment: Stirling's formula gives you a bit more than $n! \approx \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$. The "more" settles it.

Comment: @Ethan, how what you wrote helps here?

Comment: @DonAntonio Using an adjusted version of the ratio test you can show it diverges.

Comment: Could you please specify a little more, @Ethan? What "adjusted version"? What you wrote shows that $\;\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio It looks like someone just posted an answer doing what I suggested.

Comment: So I see, @Ethan, yet I think it is wrong. Do you have some link/book where this can be read?

Comment: That's the usual, ratio test @Ethan: the only one I've ever known. The limit, or the lim sup, is required there, not merely that the quotient is greater than one or not, and as expected there's clearly stated that if the limit is one then the test is inconclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$x=\frac e5\implies\;\text{we have the series}\;\;\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!5^ne^n}{n^n5^n}=\sum_{n=1}\frac{n!e^n}{n^n}$$

and now you can use [Stirling's Approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)

$$n!\sim\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

so our series behaves asimptotically (for large values of $\;n\;$) as the series

$$\frac{n^n}{e^n}\sqrt{2\pi n}\frac{e^n}{n^n}=\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

and thus clearly our series diverges.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, you saved my day!